# Is there a way of group by month in Pandas starting at specific day number?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to group by month some data in python, but i need the month to start at the 25 of each month, is there a way to do that in Pandas?

For weeks there is a way of starting on Monday, Tuesday, ... But for months it's always full month.

```
pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could offset the dates by 24 days and groupby:

```
np.random.seed(1)
dates = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-04-30', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates,
                   'val': np.random.uniform(0,1,len(dates))})

# for groupby
s = df['date'].sub(pd.DateOffset(24))

(df.groupby([s.dt.year, s.dt.month], as_index=False)
   .agg({'date':'min', 'val':'sum'})
)
```

gives

```
        date        val
0 2019-01-01  10.120368
1 2019-01-25  14.895363
2 2019-02-25  14.544506
3 2019-03-25  17.228734
4 2019-04-25   3.334160
```

Another example:

```
np.random.seed(1)
dates = pd.date_range('2019-01-20', '2019-01-30', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates,
                   'val': np.random.uniform(0,1,len(dates))})

s = df['date'].sub(pd.DateOffset(24))
df['groups'] = df.groupby([s.dt.year, s.dt.month]).cumcount()
```

gives

```
         date       val  groups
0  2019-01-20  0.417022       0
1  2019-01-21  0.720324       1
2  2019-01-22  0.000114       2
3  2019-01-23  0.302333       3
4  2019-01-24  0.146756       4
5  2019-01-25  0.092339       0
6  2019-01-26  0.186260       1
7  2019-01-27  0.345561       2
8  2019-01-28  0.396767       3
9  2019-01-29  0.538817       4
10 2019-01-30  0.419195       5
```

And you can see the how the cumcount restarts at day 25.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared the following test DataFrame:

```
         Dat  Val
0 2017-03-24    0
1 2017-03-25    0
2 2017-03-26    1
3 2017-03-27    0
4 2017-04-24    0
5 2017-04-25    0
6 2017-05-24    0
7 2017-05-25    2
8 2017-05-26    0
```

The first step is to compute a "shifted date" column:

```
df['Dat2'] = df.Dat + pd.DateOffset(days=-24)
```

The result is:

```
         Dat  Val       Dat2
0 2017-03-24    0 2017-02-28
1 2017-03-25    0 2017-03-01
2 2017-03-26    1 2017-03-02
3 2017-03-27    0 2017-03-03
4 2017-04-24    0 2017-03-31
5 2017-04-25    0 2017-04-01
6 2017-05-24    0 2017-04-30
7 2017-05-25    2 2017-05-01
8 2017-05-26    0 2017-05-02
```

As you can see, March dates in *Dat2* start just from original date *2017-03-25*,
and so on.

The value of *1* is in March (*Dat2*) and the value of *2* is in May (also *Dat2*).

Then, to compute e.g. a sum by month, we can run:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Dat2', freq='MS')).sum()
```

getting:

```
            Val
Dat2           
2017-02-01    0
2017-03-01    1
2017-04-01    0
2017-05-01    2
```

So we have correct groupping:

- *1* is in March,
- *2* is in May.

The advantage over the other answer is that you have all dates on the first
day of a month, of course bearing in mind that e.g. *2017-03-01* in the
result means the period from *2017-03-25* to *2017-04-24* (including).