# Pandas Grouper: how to use offset and origin to get a custom monthly frequency?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I want to group and sum my data over a custom date range. I want to group by a monthly range, but starting and ending with the 10th day of each month. The default `freq` values of `M` or `MS` in Pandas Grouper only allow for the first or last day of each month. Based on the documentation I would think that using the `offset` argument would allow me to start and end on the 10th day of each month, but it seems to have no effect. Also the `origin` argument seems to not have an effect either. Please see the example below:

Creating Toy DataFrame (df):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "amount"], data=[["2021-01-01", 1],
                                                    ["2021-01-02", 1],
                                                    ["2021-01-20", 1],
                                                    ["2021-02-02", 1],
                                                    ["2021-02-11", 1],
                                                    ["2021-03-05", 1],
                                                    ["2021-03-27", 1],])
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

df now looks like:

```
    date       amount
0   2021-01-01   1
1   2021-01-02   1
2   2021-01-20   1
3   2021-02-02   1
4   2021-02-11   1
5   2021-03-05   1
6   2021-03-27   1
```

Now I attempt to group by a custom monthly range using the `offset` argument. I wish it to range from the 10th day of each month to the 9th day of the next month. In addition, I wish to begin my grouping on `2021-01-05`, disregarding previous days.

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq="1MS", closed="left",
                      offset="10D", origin="2021-01-05")).sum()
```

Expected output:

```
           amount
date    
2021-01-10   2
2021-02-10   2
2021-03-10   1
```

Actual output:

```
           amount
date    
2021-01-01   3
2021-02-01   2
2021-03-01   2
```

As you can see, it looks like neither the `offset` nor the `origin` arguments are being taken into account!

Edit 1: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081662/is-there-a-way-of-group-by-month-in-pandas-starting-at-specific-day-number) is relevant in that the end goal is similar, but the use of `offset` and `origin` are not asked about. Also the answers to that question are not sufficient.

Edit 2: Removed image of code and outputs, and replaced with text code.

Comment: kindly share reproducible example with expected output

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Updated to address your comments, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Months are hard to tame ...

You could use the following approach using [`pd.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html#) and [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
start, end = df.date.iloc[0], df.date.iloc[-1]
ms1_d10 = pd.DateOffset(months=1, day=10)
bins = pd.date_range(start - ms1_d10, end + ms1_d10, freq=ms1_d10)
result = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.date, bins=bins)).sum()
```

With the DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"date": ["2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-10", "2021-02-02",
              "2021-02-11", "2021-03-05", "2021-03-27"],
     "amount": 1}
)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

this leads to

```
                          amount
date                            
(2020-12-10, 2021-01-10]       3
(2021-01-10, 2021-02-10]       1
(2021-02-10, 2021-03-10]       2
(2021-03-10, 2021-04-10]       1
```

If you don't like the intervals you could use labels:

```
result = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.date, bins=bins, labels=bins[1:])).sum()
```

```
                     amount
date                       
2021-01-10 00:00:00       3
2021-02-10 00:00:00       1
2021-03-10 00:00:00       2
2021-04-10 00:00:00       1
```

Comment: This seems to get the job done! Thank you Timus. 
I am still interested in answers that can use `Grouper` with the `offset` and `origin` arguments, so I gave you an upvote but did not accept your answer (at least not yet).

Comment: @DataMan Thanks for the feedback! I've struggled quite a bit with the `Grouper` to get something similar done - to no avail. I'm curious myself if I've missed something obvious. (Months are a tricky thing. I once was so frustrated that I started writing an extension class of `timedelta` that includes months - just to realise midway through, that `dateutils` already has a great solution.)

Comment: It is not specific to month frequency as it is similar to the week frequency The origin parameter seems to have no effect when we want to adjust the start of the bins.